# A special Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want to have a restriction a string which can accept alphanumeric values and hiphen.
  I am providing 3 examples to have a clear idea.
  1) AS15JKM-125TR-325AMOR
  2) ITEW32-DE432OI
  3) 09IURE765EDR

There is no specific pattern, There may b 0 to 3 hiphens in a string.
  I just want to restrict it in such a way that it should accept only alphanumeric value and
  only Hiphen, no other special character.
  plz help me on this.

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1: No Lookahead**

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*-){0,3}[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Note that if you only want uppercase letters, you need to remove `a-z`

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The non-capturing group `(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*-)` matches zero or more letters or digit, then a hyphen
- This is repeated zero to three times, enforcing your limit on hyphens
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` matches one or more letters or digit
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Option 2: With Lookahead**

This does not present any benefit over the first version, I am just showing it for completion.

```
^(?=(?:[^-]*-){0,3}[^-]*$)[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**Explanation**

The lookahead `(?=(?:[^-]*-){0,3}[^-]*$)` asserts that what follows is

- `(?:[^-]*-)` any number of non-hyphens, followed by a hyphen
- `{0,3}` zero to three times
- then `[^-]*$` any number of non-hyphens and the end of the string

**Option 3: With Negative Lookahead**

Courtesy of @Jerry:

```
^(?!(?:[^-]*-){4})[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**Explanation**

The negative lookahead `(?!(?:[^-]*-){4})` asserts that it is not possible to find a non-hyphen followed by a hyphen four times.

Comment: Option 3: With negative lookahead: `^(?!(?:[^-]*-){4})[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Comment: @Jerry Great call, thank you. :) Added it with explanation and proper credit, removed the comma in `{4,}`

Comment: Can we make `*` possessive: `*+`? It will (probably) help when there's no match, to prevent computation caused by backtracking.

Comment: @Unihedron I like your thinking. :) But when the only tag is `regex` I tend to avoid possessive quants, which are only available in Perl, PCRE, Ruby, and (surprisingly) Java. On the other hand, `(?> ... )` has more support—but no Python and JS. Granted, there is the [`(?=(foo))\1` hack](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.html#pseudo-atomic-groups).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to count the hyphens, something like so should work: `^[A-Z0-9 -]+$`.

An example of the regex is available [here](http://regex101.com/r/oO3aE5/2).

Comment: it allows more than three hypens.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Hence my assumption. If the OP want to count the hyphens, then he/she should opt for the other answer.